# Add custom error highlighting in PhpStorm when single equals in php if condition

Tags: php, error-handling, phpstorm

Yes, using a single equals in a php if condition is sometimes desired, but how can I set a custom error in PhpStorm on the below code to prevent me from doing so?

mark as error when:

```
if (a = b) {
    //crap I just reassigned a when I wanted to check if a == b
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an inspection for that already -- just use it.

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Probable bugs -> Assignment in condition`

[image]

It works just fine:

[image]

Severity can be changed from "Warning" to "Error" if needed.

---

**NOTE:**
Obviously, it will now highlight ALL such assignments .. not just this particular place. But you can *create custom scope* and turn it on or off for files in those scopes.

For particular place it can also be suppressed via special comment:

```
/** @noinspection PhpAssignmentInConditionInspection */
if ($a = $b) {
    echo 'hello!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lazyone. I have tried that option before, but I only want it showing an error if it's specifically in an 'if' condition. I have a lot of functions with default parameter values `function a(b,c = false ){}` as well as while loops `while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)){}` and I don't want to add the no inspection block comment everywhere to ignore those cases. Going to leave this open to see if someone can point me in the right direction for setting a custom error handling rule....

Comment: @derekcbaldwin This inspection does not issue any warnings for a valid code like `function a($b,$c = false ){}` where default values is a normal/ordinary approach (nothing fancy by any means). But yes -- it will issue warnings for `while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)){}` .. as it's exactly the same as `if ($a=$b)` -- assignment in condition.